# testing a delete method in jUnit using jdbcTemplate and DAO Layer

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

i'm trying to test my delete method but i don't know how can i do that, i tried inside my test delete method to invoke my searchByID with the id of the User i deleted to create a null variable and then use `assertNull`

like this:

```
    @Test
    public void deleteUser() 
    {

        userDAO.deleteUserById(3);
        User nullUser  =  userDAO.searchUserById(3);
        assertNull(nullUser);
    }
```

but this give me this error:

```
expected null but was domain.User@c506pb
```

i tried to use the exception approach, since i can whatch in my output that that code generates a `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found`
 i tried like this :

```
    @Test(expected=SQLException.class)
    public void deleteUser() 
    {

         userDAO.deleteUserById(3);
        Usuario usuarioVacio  =  usuarioDAO.buscarUsuarioPorId(3);

    }
```

but this give me this error:

```
Expected exception: java.sql.SQLException
java.lang.AssertionError
```

here is my delete method implementation

```
@Override
public void deleteUserById(int idUser)
{

    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        String storedProcedure =  "{ call deleteUserById(?) }";

        connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureBorrarUSuario);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, idUser);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(connection != null)
        try 
        {
            connection.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the method works since it deletes the correct user, i will like to do it using both approachs the exception approach and the other one, but i dont know why is not working

***EDIT:***

here is my searchById method

```
@Override
    public Usuario buscarUsuarioPorId(int userId) 
    {
        User user=  new  User();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            String storedProcedureInfoUsuario  =  "{ call searchUserById(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";

            connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureInfoUsuario);

            callableStatement.setInt(1, idUsuario);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

            callableStatement.executeQuery();

            //
            user.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
            user.setLastName(callableStatement.getString(3));
            user.setEmail(callableStatement.getString(4));
            user.setState(callableStatement.getString(5));
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
//          Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAOImplementacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(connection != null)
            try 
            {
                connection.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return usuario;
    }
```

and here is my PL/SQL searchById

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE searchUserById
    (
       p_userId IN User.user_id%TYPE,
       ps_name OUT User.name%TYPE,
       ps_lastName OUT User.lastName%TYPE,
       ps_email OUT User.email%TYPE,
       ps_state OUT User.state%TYPE
    )
IS
BEGIN

  SELECT name, lastName, email, state
  INTO ps_name , ps_lastName , ps_email , ps_state 
  FROM  USER WHERE user_id= p_userid;

END;
/
```

and here is my delete PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deleteUserById
    (
       p_userId IN USER.user_ID%TYPE
    )
IS
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM USER
  WHERE user_id=p_userId;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

***EDIT 2***

i created this suggested method but it gives me a error that i'm missing a return value so i added return null

```
 @Override
public void deleteUserById(final int idUser) {

    final String storedProcedureBorrarUSuario =  "{ call borrarUsuarioPorId(?) }";
    final Connection connection = null;

    jdbcTemplate.execute( new ConnectionCallback<Object>() 
    {
        @Override
        public Object doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException, DataAccessException 
        {
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureBorrarUSuario);
            callableStatement.setInt(1, idUser);
            callableStatement.executeUpdate();
            return null;

        }
    });   
}
```

and when i run my unit test it says null pointer exception in this line

userDAO.deleteUserById(3);

***EDIT 3***

i tried with this seting firts the user as null so if there's a exception my method returns a null object but still i have the same problem in my unit test when i try to use the exception approach

```
@Override
public Usuario searchUserById(int userId) 
{
    User user=  null;
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        String storedProcedureInfoUsuario  =  "{ call searchUserById(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";

        connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureInfoUsuario);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, userId);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();

        //
        user=  new User();
        usuario.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
        usuario.setLastName(callableStatement.getString(3));
        usuario.setEmail(callableStatement.getString(4));
        usuario.setState(callableStatement.getString(5));
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
//          Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAOImplementacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(connection != null)
            try 
            {
                connection.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
```

here is my unit test that i expect to have a null value this works with the modfications i did

```
public void findUserById()
{
    User emptyUser=  userDAO.searchUserById(50);
    assertNull(emptyUser);
}
```

but instead if i try to use the exception approach i have the following error

```
@Test(expected=SQLException.class) 
public void findUserById()
    {
        User emptyUser=  userDAO.searchUserById(50);
        assertNull(emptyUser);
    }
```

this give me `Expected exception: java.sql.SQLException
    java.lang.AssertionError`

i dont know why this not work if i have the following exception in my output 
`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found`

Comment: Please post the implementation of `searchUserById`

Comment: You aren't using the `JdbcTemplate` ... And why are you using a SP to delete a user?

Comment: yes i'm using jdbcTemplate to create the connection
`connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();`
and i'm using a SP because  i think that my code is more encapsulated in that way

Comment: No you aren't yuo are just using the datasource, yuo are basically using a complex way to obtain a connection...

Comment: is that bad pratice? it would be more efficient if i get the connection in a traditional way?, i'm using jdbcTemplate becasue i think later i would add some easy sql procedures and i dont want them to be created it as SP

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum i debug the code and it stops in this line: `jdbcTemplate.execute( new ConnectionCallback<Object>() ` and give me nullPointer exception

Comment: Because you haven't read my modified answer and haven't applied the correct changes... Check the code in my answer.

Comment: No they aren't... You still have `Connection connection = null;` and are using that `connection.prepareCall`, connection is always null. Whereas my code doesn't have that as it uses the passed in `Connection` named `con`. So no your code doesn't match...

Comment: hey @M.Deinum you where right i was missing those details, i tried your method and it worked but can you please explain in your answer what are the differences between calling the method with `ConnectionCallback<Object>` and they way i did in my last edit, i know that you wrote that i don't have to open and close connections by myself  but is this the only difference??and is this reliable?, what is the best pratice to do this? using `ConnectionCallback`  or  the way that i have in my last edit, since it works in both ways

Comment: It saves you writing a lot of code, and if you use spring managed transactions you are garantueed to use the same connection. IN yuor case you would get a new connection each time you requested one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your method serachUserById(). I fixed it for you in the code bellow. You always returned a user object. No matter if there was a user in the database or not. The code bellow first assigns null to the user. I guess there is an exception if there is no user with this userId. So you catch the exception and continue returning null. If there is a user in the DB you will create a User object, fill it with values and return that one.

The key point is to distinguish between
1. There is a user and I return it with a User object and
2. There is not user and I return null.

```
@Override
public User serachUserById(int userId) 
{
    User user = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        String storedProcedureInfoUsuario  =  "{ call searchUserById(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";

        connection  =  jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(storedProcedureInfoUsuario);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, userId);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();

        //
        user = new User();
        user.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
        user.setLastName(callableStatement.getString(3));
        user.setEmail(callableStatement.getString(4));
        user.setState(callableStatement.getString(5));
    } 
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {

Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAOImplementacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(connection != null)
        try 
        {
            connection.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

Anyway I would recommend you to work with spring jpa repositories instead of jdbc connections, SQL and stored procedures. You will save a lot of time and bugs.

Comment: Hi meskobalazs. Yes, it was not exactly an answer. But unfortunately I can not yet comment foreign questions. I edited my post and think I have now written an appropriate answer.

Comment: You didn't really get what `@Test(expected=SQLException.class) ` means. Your test won't recognize the exception if you catch it in your search method. It will only be recognized if the exception is thrown out of your search method and your test method.

Comment: You must decide how your search method should behave. In case of no user found you either return null. So **only** your `assertNull()` test makes sense. Or you don't catch the SQLException and throw it out of your search method (`throws SQLException`). So **only** the `@Test(expected=SQLException.class) ` test makes sense. Maybe have a look at Java Exceptions and JUnit4.

Answer (score 0):

There could be below possibilities

1. There is problem within your PL/SQL.
   See when you are getting that exception? While deleting user or while searching the user.
2. What's the configuration value set for defaultRollback in your transaction configuration of the test context? If it is true that means your changes are getting rolled back after execution of test method and that's why you might be getting value in search user
3. If everything else is all-right then there might be issue with transaction boundaries.

Comment: 1) `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found` do you mean that exception? i get that exception because i'm trying to select a data that don't exist becasue i already deleted it, so that means that my deleted method works fine, i'm having problems is with my test

2)i don't know how to look that configuration, i dont think i'm getting a rollback because the user gets deleted after i run the method

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would suggest you rewrite your JDBC code and actually use the `JdbcTemplate`. Instead of managing connections yourself, wrap your logic in a `ConnectionCallback` saves you from opening/closing a connection.

Second for modifications you should use `executeUpdate` ins

```
@Override
public void deleteUserById(final int idUser) {
    final String storedProcedure =  "{ call deleteUserById(?) }";
    getJdbcTemplate().execute(new ConnectionCallback<Object>() {
        public Object doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall(storedProcedureBorrarUSuario);
            callableStatement.setInt(1, idUser);
            callableStatement.executeUpdate();
            return null;
        }
    });   
}

@Override
public Usuario buscarUsuarioPorId(final int userId) {       
    User user=  new  User();
    final String storedProcedureInfoUsuario  =  "{ call searchUserById(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
    return getJdbcTemplate().execute(new ConnectionCallback<User>() {
        public User doInConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall(storedProcedureInfoUsuario);

        callableStatement.setInt(1, idUsuario);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);

        callableStatement.executeQuery();
        //
        user.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
        user.setLastName(callableStatement.getString(3));
        user.setEmail(callableStatement.getString(4));
        user.setState(callableStatement.getString(5));

    });
}
```

Comment: i edited my question with the delete user method, but says that i'm missing a return value so i added return null i edited my question with more details

Comment: @M.Denium so at the end it only would save me write code, since i'm not using transaction annotations, in both cases using `ConnectionCallback` or `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();` i would create a new connection each time right? do you know of about a good tutorial to learn the combination of jdbctemplae and transactions annontations